# how to add a button which calls a webservice in my custom admin menu page of prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

how to add a button and a text box in which when I click the button it calls a webservice in my custom admin menu page of prestashop, ie i am developing a  admin module  in which i created a menu and i am able to display grid with pagination the defalut prestashop grid in that page , but i want a button and a text box above the grid how to do this  in prestashop 1.6.

here is my controllers code:

```
class QueryController extends ModuleAdminController
{

public $module;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->module = new querydr();     
    $this->addRowAction('view');
    //$this->removeButton('add'); //  this code to remove the add button
    $this->explicitSelect = false;
    $this->context = Context::getContext();
    $this->id_lang = $this->context->language->id;
    $this->lang = false;
    $this->ajax = 1;
    $this->path = _MODULE_DIR_.'querydr';
    $this->default_form_language = $this->context->language->id;
    $dormant_filter_days= Configuration::get('DORMANTUSERS_DORMANT_FILTER_DAYS');
    $this->table = 'query_dr';
    $this->className = 'QueryDr';
    $this->identifier = 'id_query_dr';
    $this->allow_export = true;
    $this->_select = " id_query_dr,order_no,ni_online_ref_id,transaction_type,response,status,error_code,error_msg,date_add,date_upd    
            ";
    $this->name = 'Query';
    //d( $this->select);
    $this->bootstrap = true;
    $this->fields_list = array(

    'id_query_dr' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Id'),
    'align' => 'text-center',
    'remove_onclick' => true,
    'search' => false,
    ),

    'order_no' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Order Number'),
    'align' => 'text-center',
    'remove_onclick' => true,
    //'search' => false,
    ),
    'ni_online_ref_id' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Online Reference ID '),
    'align' => 'text-center',
    'remove_onclick' => true,
    //'search' => false,
    ),        
    'transaction_type' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Transaction type'),
    'align' => 'text-center',
    'remove_onclick' => true
    ), 
     'status' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Status'),
    'align' => 'text-center',
    'remove_onclick' => true
    ),  
             'error_code' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Error Code'),
    'align' => 'text-center',
    'remove_onclick' => true
    ), 
             'error_msg' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Error Message'),
    'align' => 'text-center',
    'remove_onclick' => true
    ), 
             'date_add' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Date Added'),
    'align' => 'text-center',
    'remove_onclick' => true
    ), 
             'date_upd' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('date_upd'),
    'align' => 'text-center',
    'remove_onclick' => true
    ),     
    );


    parent::__construct();
}




public function initPageHeaderToolbar()
{
    $this->page_header_toolbar_title = $this->l('Query Dr Logs');
    parent::initPageHeaderToolbar();
}

public function initToolbar()
{
    parent::initToolbar();
    $this->context->smarty->assign('toolbar_scroll', 1);
    $this->context->smarty->assign('show_toolbar', 1);
    $this->context->smarty->assign('toolbar_btn', $this->toolbar_btn);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the method initContent().
Example :

```
/**
  * @see AdminController::initContent
  */
public function initContent()
{
 $this->getLanguages();
 $this->initToolbar();
 $this->initTabModuleList();
 $this->initPageHeaderToolbar();
 $this->content .= $this->renderModulesList();
 $this->content .= $this->renderKpis();
 $this->content .= $this->renderMyCustomFormList();
 $this->content .= $this->renderList();
 $this->content .= $this->renderStats();
 $this->content .= $this->renderOptions();
 $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'page_header_toolbar_btn' => $this->page_header_toolbar_btn,
                    'show_page_header_toolbar' => $this->show_page_header_toolbar,
                    'page_header_toolbar_title' => $this->page_header_toolbar_title,
                    'title' => $this->page_header_toolbar_title,
                    'toolbar_btn' => $this->page_header_toolbar_btn,

                'content' => $this->content,
                'lite_display' => $this->lite_display,
                'url_post' => self::$currentIndex . '&token=' . $this->token
  ));
}
```

And your render for your form :

```
public function renderMyCustomFormList()
{
        $html = $this->context->smarty->fetch(
            parent::getTemplatePath().'my_template_form_list.tpl'
        );
        return ($html);
}
```